# Counting basic operations in function call

Tags: java, big-o, complexity-theory

I've been given a simple pseudocode and told to determine the big O running time of the function myMethod() by counting the approximate number of operations it performs. The thing I am unsure about is that within the while loop of the function myMethod() there is a function call to doIt(), in which there is another while loop. I know that I need to include the operations within doIt(), however I am unsure if it should count as n or n^2 since it is a separate function, despite it being a while loop within a while loop.

I've written what I think the number of basic operations is for each line beside their respective lines, I would appreciate some guidance on this problem as I've looked around on the internet but not much luck regarding this specific issue.

```
static int doIt(int n)
{
  count = 0 //1
  j=1 //1
  while j < n  //n x n
  {
   count = count +1 //n x n
   j=j+2 //n x n
  }
   return count //1
}



static int myMethod (int n)
{
  i = 1 //1
  while(i<n) //log n
 {
   dolt(i) //log n
   i = ix2 //log n
 }
  return 1; //1
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like Python code.

Comment: looks like c# to me

Comment: Inside the `doIt` fucntion, you have the while loop commeted as `n x n`. Why do you expect this while loop to execute that many times? I'd have expected it to execute about `n / 2` times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `doIt` function is a basic while loop. I don't know what `n*n` is supposed to mean, but that loop is not `O(n^2)`, its `O(N)` because it executes `n/2` times- which we can write as `1/2 * n`, and since we don't care about constants in terms of writing Big-O notation, we can say `doIt` has a Big-O complexity of `O(N)`

You correctly identified `myMethod`'s loop to be `log(N)` time. Since the `doIt` function runs in `O(N)` time- the overall complexity of `myMethod` is `log(N)` for the complexity of the outer loop multiplied by the complexity of `doIt`- so `log(N) * N` which equals `O(nlog(n))`